# how to set, get a variable in java

Tags: java, variables, get, set

I have to implement this class and the 2 methods but dont know how. How do i set the variable and get it again?
Heres my starting point:

```
public class VariableStorage<T> implements IVariableStorage<T> {
        public void set(T var);
        public T get();
    }
```

and this is what i have tried:

```
public void set(T var) {
        char T = 1;
    }
    public T get() {
        return T;
    }
```

in the second step i have to implement this but dont really have a clue how to do this:

```
public interface ITextStorage < T extends CharSequence > extends
IVariableStorage <T > {
/**
* Counts the number of equal characters in same positions of
* the texts stored in this ITextStorage and the other storage .
* Example : ’abcdef ’ and ’abba ’ have two matching characters
* in the first two positions .
*
* @param other the other text storage
* @return the number of matching characters
*/
public int countMatchingCharacters ( ITextStorage <? > other ) ;
}
```

i tried creating 2 arrays and comparing the entries but cant get a code that workes.

Comment: Just a hint: since ``var`` became a keyword in java, it's not the best idea to use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need to have a class field, which will store the value that was set:

   ```
   public class VariableStorage<T> implements IVariableStorage<T> {
        private T t;

        @Override
        public void set(T var) {
            t = var;
        }

        @Override
        public T get() {
            return t; // what will happen if t wasn't set and get() was called? 
        } // is that expected behavior?
    }
   ```
2. Now, you should be able to create an implementation of ITextStorage.

   In the method, you can do:

   ```
   public int countMatchingCharacters(ITextStorage<?> other) {
      int matchingCharsCount = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < this.t.get().length(); i++) {
          if(this.t.get().charAt(i) == other.get().charAt(i)){
              matchingCharsCount++;
          }
      }

      return matchingCharsCount;
   }
   ```